# How to create an empty array only in first iteration of loop and then keep using it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, recursion

I am **new to javascript**. I have two functions, one called arrayToList which takes an array and produces a list from it, the other is called **listToArray** which takes a list and produces array from it. first one is working fine. However, in case of second one I have to **create an empty array in the first iteration only** of a for or while loop within which I will pass on each value of list to array I have created and at each step remove list.value
and set the list to list.rest (that is rest of list) and then recursively keep calling the same function.

**My problem** is that I am not able to declare the array within the function. If I say `if(!array) {let array=[];}` then I get message that array is undefined, if I declare array as global then it is retaining values across different calls to function, which I don't want. Below is the code. Thanks for your help.

```
let array=[];


function listToArray(list) {
  
  while(list.value) {
    
    array.push(list.value);
    delete list.value;
    list=list.rest;
    listToArray(list);
    
   }
  
  return array;
 
  
}

console.log(listToArray({value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: {
value:  30
rest:   {value: 50, rest: {value: 70, …}}));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a default 2nd parameter that defaults to the empty array, then pass it along:

```js
function nestedObjToArray(obj, arr = []) {
  arr.push(obj.value);
  if (obj.rest) {
    nestedObjToArray(obj.rest, arr);
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(nestedObjToArray({
  value: 10,
  rest: {
    value: 20,
    rest: {
      value: 30,
      rest: {
        value: 50,
        rest: {
          value: 70,
        }
      }
    }
  }
}))
```

This way, the array gets created the first time the function is called, because the function isn't initially called with a second parameter. On subsequent recursive calls, the created array is passed down as the second parameter.

Note that "list" is not something with a generally-understood universal meaning in JS. Some might think you're referring to a plain array. Since what you're passing is a nested object, you might call the function `nestedObjToArray` or something similar.

If you can't pass another parameter, you can create the array on the final recursive call and return it:

```js
function nestedObjToArray(obj) {
  const arr = obj.rest ? nestedObjToArray(obj.rest) : [];
  arr.unshift(obj.value);
  return arr;
};

console.log(nestedObjToArray({
  value: 10,
  rest: {
    value: 20,
    rest: {
      value: 30,
      rest: {
        value: 50,
        rest: {
          value: 70,
        }
      }
    }
  }
}))
```

Comment: Hi @CertainPerformance, thanx for the answer. Your method is a good way of achieving desired effect,  I also thought of something like what you have written but my question is if there is a way we can do it without having to pass a second parameter? If we don't pass second parameter in method call then will it automatically create array?

Comment: You can create the array at the final recursive call, but it's more confusing that way IMO

Comment: ok, I had forgotten how to use default parameters. thanx for reminding, your method is the way to go. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a recursive approach without using an array for collecting nested items.

```js
function nestedObjToArray({ value, rest }) {
    return [value, ...(rest ? nestedObjToArray(rest) : [])];
}

console.log(nestedObjToArray({ value: 10, rest: { value: 20, rest: { value: 30, rest: { value: 50, rest: { value: 70 } } } } }));
```

Comment: Hi Nina, thanx for answer. it works but I don't want to pass a second parameter preferably, I am noob so your code seems i bit difficult for me to understand. anyway, thanx for help, @CertainPerformance has provided alternatives to your method which are a bit easier to understand. I will use your method when I am no longer a noob :), right now it scares me.

Comment: @sb16: There is only one parameter there.  It's simply destructured to allow direct access to its properties.  This is equivalent to `const listToArray = (x) => [x.value, ...(x.rest ? listToArray(x.rest) : [])]`